# Facebook can create apps or features if you use their API to use their features

Tags: facebook

I have a plan to create an app and using Facebook API's would be good as I can easily use many features from Facebook, but I have seen that one of their policies is this:

`We can create apps or products that offer features and services similar to your app.`

How would a patent on my app work with this Facebook policy, would it be better to use my own features not related to that app if the chance the app became successful?

It is located at section 6, Things you should know, specifically number 9.

[Facebook developer policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/)

Comment: Could you provide the full policy or a link? It's hard to say from that except if it's meant to be a license or just an information.

Comment: @DonQuiKong adding now

Comment: To me that looks like aiming at waving any competition regulations the contract could imply, not like a license for your IP. But my knowledge on that topic has yet to grow and it might vary per jurisdiction. You could try asking Facebook, that should get you a definite answer.

Comment: Getting a patent on an app isn't the easiest thing either.